# troubleshoot sporadic SSL "bad record MAC" exception in influxdb

Tags: linux, ssl, tls1.2, influxdb, tls1.3

We recently updated our influxdb configuration (to reduce SWEET32 issues) as follows:

```
[http]
  auth-enabled = true
  pprof-enabled = false
  flux-enabled = true
  https-enabled = true
  https-certificate = "client.crt"
  https-private-key = "client.key"
  [tls]
    min-version = "tls1.2"
    max-version = "tls1.3"
    # https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Intermediate_compatibility_.28recommended.29
    #
    # Can this be configured more cleanly?  
    # strict-ciphers didn't work / or not sure on where to configure it
    ciphers = [ "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
                "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
                "TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256",
                "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
                "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
                "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
                "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
                "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305",
                "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305",
                "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
              ]
```

Anyway the configuration seemd to running fine for a while and then suddenly yesterday our influxdb became in accessible. Grafana started throwing 502 errors and trying to do curl commands:

```
curl --fail --silent --show-error -k -u grafana_user:<redacted> -G "https://10.0.67.1:8086/query?db=metrics" --data-urlencode "q=select LAST(value) from /^some.metric*/ where time > now() - 1m"
```

Failed with `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.0.67.1 port 8086: Connection refused`

On restarting the VM ofcourse everything worked back again. On checking the logs the error stated on influxdb was

```
http: TLS handshake error from 10.0.67.6:38084: local error: tls: bad record MAC
```

How could this be debugged, and what could be the possible ways to fix this?

Using influxdb: 1.8.10

Comment: Too little debugging info to answer. Is this during setup or somewhere during a connection? Which cipher suite is actually chosen? I'd at least use a sniffer and try many connections until it happens again. Furthermore, I'd propose a full memory scan because a single bit error will trigger a bad MAC. Are you using ECC memory? Note that as there is no programming involved, it makes more sense to post this at [sf], preferably with more details.